# How to change fontStyle and border color of VictoryTooltip

Tags: reactjs, victory-charts

How can change following things in VictoryTooltip component:
- font style
- border color of tooltip
- padding around tooltip text

Answer (score 3):

Here's an example of a custom tooltip with :

- custom font size;
- custom border radius;
- the default arrow disabled;
- custom border and background.

Note that styling `VictoryChart` elements often needs to use `svg` styling options, not CSS (i.e. `fill` instead of `background-color`).

```html
<VictoryTooltip
  style={{fontSize: '25px'}}
  cornerRadius={20}
  pointerLength={0}
  flyoutStyle={{
    stroke: "tomato",
    strokeWidth: 4,
    fill: "yellow",
  }}
/>
```

Example in action : https://codesandbox.io/s/victory-tooltip-styling-e985k